# NextJs unable to prefetch request using React-Query in docker (connect ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: reactjs, docker, next.js, react-query

Hello I have an application running locally in the docker. Frontend is using NextJS while backend is my custom expressJS server.

My client is running on `http://localhost:3000/` while server is `http://localhost:5000/`

Whenever I make an request client-side using base url `http://localhost:5000/api` it works fine, but whenever I try to prefetch a query using React-Query library prefetching in `getServerSideProps` I am receiving an error:

> AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000

I found a solution by changing my base url to `http://server:5000/api` however this then stops the requests from working in the browser.

What would be the best solution to maintain the same base url across client and server?

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  ui:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./ui
    container_name: client-ui
    volumes:
      - ./ui:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - default
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
  server:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server
    container_name: server
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/dist
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - default
volumes:
  mongodb_data:
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Are Next and Express running in their own separate containers, both in the same container, or is the only container in this setup for Express? It might help to include the `Dockerfile`(s) (or `docker-compose.yml` if that's being used) and/or the `docker` command (with flags) that's being invoked.

Comment: Hey, yes sure I've attached docker-compose file that I am using. I run the app using `docker compose up --build`

Comment: The client code running in the end-user's browser and the code actually running in containers have different network environments and will need different URLs.

Comment: So I assume the only solution is to use different url client/server side.

Comment: @Rvfvl You could also explore using a reverse proxy like Nginx or Caddy. For example, I have a Next.js frontend (port 3000) paired with a Vert.x backend (port 8080) behind Caddy (port 80). All my backend API routes start with `/api/v1/*` so Caddy sends those matches to Vert.x while everything else gets sent to Next. In this setup, there's only one base URL (Caddy/localhost on port 80) on the client/browser side to worry about.